# Why does GoDoc not show interface variables?

Tags: interface, documentation, go

Considering the following snippet:

```
package example

type Foo interface {
}

var Alpha = "alpha"
var Beta string = "beta"
var Gamma Foo = "gamma"
```

Both `godoc` (`-http=:6060`) and `go doc` ignore `Gamma` entirely, whilst `Alpha` and `Beta` are - of course - shown in the output. This behavior seems to be reproducible with any exported variable that is declared to be an interface type.

Why?

Comment: What version of Go and what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Go 1.0.2, in particular the APT packages from Debian Wheezy (`golang` and `golang-doc`) version 1.0.2-1.1 --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unconfirmed at my system. I see all, including Gamma.

Var Gamma is placed after type Foo definition.

But at my system a devel version of golang is installed:

go version devel +1140207a3395 Wed Nov 20 13:47:37 2013 -0800 linux/amd64

Comment: Indeed, `Gamma` is placed directly after `Foo`. I've expected it to occur in the "Variables" section, though, and not even thought of searching in another place - especially because it doesn't appear in the "Index", which is kind of awkward. Anyway, thank you!